# NETSDK1135 SupportedOSPlatformVersion 10.0.19041.0 cannot be higher than TargetPlatformVersion 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-4.8

I am trying to convert a .NET Framework WPF app to .NET 5

I ran https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert, and removed some incompatible DLL refs.

Now, when I try to compile, I am presented with

```
NETSDK1135  SupportedOSPlatformVersion 10.0.19041.0 cannot be higher than TargetPlatformVersion 7.0
```

[image]

Any ideas as to what to look for?
The project in question is a combination of .NET 5 and .NET Standard 2.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same error a few hours ago.
I found this article useful: https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/net-5-tfms/
As I understand the TargetFrameWork in the project file must include the same Windows version as the SDK Contract.
My project file looks like this now:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

...

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" Version="10.0.19041.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

...

Hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 15):

This issue appeared on my end when adding **Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts** to read the version applied during packaging using MSIX package.

I tried with @RolandJS solution, but still tons of errors.

Found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

It mentions that since .NET 5 (or a later release) and target Windows 10, version 1809 or a later, the **Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts** is **not** needed anymore. Instead you should use the TargetFrameworkMoniker (TFM).

As mentioned by RolandJS already:
In the project file change

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

to e.g.

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

Uninstall **Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts**

Comment: this was what i needed! thank you

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 15 times. This should be *the* answer!!